# How to set element in horizontally in html?

Tags: html, css

How to set 0 and like in one line?

```
 <span>
                <div id="count">0</div>
                <a>Like</a>
            </span>
```

what i tried is : http://jsfiddle.net/ZzXru/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never nest a block level element inside an inline element
You are nesting a `div` element inside a `span` element.
I just altered your HTML a bit

```
<span>
     <span id="count">0</span>
     <a>Like</a>
</span>
```

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzXru/6/)**

**[More on block elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements)**

**[More on inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements)**

Answer (score 2):

```
#count{
    display:inline;
}
```

or without the css, (ie using the standard form for span and div)

```
<span id='count'>0</span>
<a>Like</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `#count { display: inline; }` to your CSS.

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/hkEA5/